# iPhone -- How to upload Email attachments to server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, file-upload, gdata-api

HI ALL,

I am making an application for iPhone in that I want to upload any document or any file that is coming from email as an attachment.

Like I am receiving a Untitled.doc and Untitled.xls files as attachment in Email. Receiving email email in my iPhone , now I want to upload the same to my server then is it possible with iPhone as I do come to know that we don't have permission to access the file system of iPhone,

If this thing is possible then how to perform can any one provide code or tutorial

**Can any one tell me where the email attachments are stored in the iPhone ??**

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application cannot read the user inbox.  If your application wants to have Microsoft Word documents and Excel spreadsheet, it will have to register with iOS that it can handle those types of documents.  [Introduction to Uniform Type Identifiers Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319)

Then when the user selects the attachment in the e-mail message, your application will be listed in "Open in..." dialog presented to the user.  If the user if selects your app, your app will get the URL of document. At that point you can upload the file to the server.

Comment: Thanks Black Frog for this tutorial , and also can you please let me know that register with ios means ? Is it same as creating the developer account or any other process to follow  ?

Comment: What I mean by registering with iOS, is that you have to list the documents you can handle in the info.plist [Configuring Application on iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/115-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement your own email client. [libetpan](http://www.etpan.org/libetpan/index.html) works quite well for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but can you please provide some tutorial ?